# Setting value of row in certain column based on a slice of pandas dataframe - using both loc and iloc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to slice my dataframe based on a certain condition, and select the first row of that slice, and set the value of the column of that first row.

```
index  COL_A. COL.B. COLC
0.     cond_A1 cond_B1.  0
1      cond_A1 cond_B1.  0
2      cond_A1 cond_B1.  0
3      cond_A2 cond_B2.  0
4.     cond_A2 cond_B2.  0
```

Neither of the following lines of code I have attempted update the dataframe

```
df.loc[((df['COL_A'] == cond_A1) & (df['COL_B'] == cond_b1)), 'COL_C'].iloc[0] = 1
df[((df['COL_A'] == cond_A1) & (df['COL_B'] == cond_b1))].iloc[0]['COL_C'] = 1
```

I need to be able to loop through the conditions so that I could apply the same code to the next set of conditions, and update the COL_C row with index 3 based on these new conditions.

Comment: conditions are different for different rows? If yes how are they applied on rows? I mean how do you know what condition should row 10 for example meet?

Comment: The conditions result in large slices of the dataframe returning, so conda1 and condb1 would return the df from 0-2 inclusive. I only want to change the first row of colC though based on that 0-2, and col_c index 3 based on the other conditions

Comment: It doesn't matter what happens on row10, if a solution works for this df if will be a solution

Comment: I updated my answer, please take a look. If i understan correcty, you want to update only the first row of each slice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update only the first row of your slice with the following code:

```
df.loc[df.loc[(df['COL_A'] == cond_A1) & (df['COL_B'] == cond_b1), 'COL_C'].index[0], 'COL_C'] = 1
```